# iOS: device orientation events never arrive after startup

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I have an OpenGL game that needs to be aware of the device's orientation (i.e. portrait vs landscape).

The APIs seem pretty straightforward... the relevant parts of my ViewController are:

```
@implementation MyViewController

- (id)init
{
    ...

    // Get orientation events
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(didRotate:)
        name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
    ...
}

-(void)didRotate:(NSNotification*)notification 
{   
    NSLog(@"didRotate %d", orientation);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    NSLog(@"shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation %d", orientation);
    return YES;
}

@end
```

What happens is that I get a few calls during startup:

```
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation 3
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation 3
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation 3
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation 3
didRotate 4
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation 4
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation 4
didRotate 1
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation 1
```

After which the UIView and the EAGLContext are set up, it starts rendering and everything looks great, but shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation and didRotate are never called again, no matter how much I rotate the phone while the game is playing.

What could I be doing wrong for this to be happening?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this is slightly embarrassing...

Turns out the portrait mode lock was on.

DOH!